# I can't import modules in function

Tags: python

```
def imp():
    import random
def choi(a):
    random.choice(a)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    imp()
    choi(['a', 'b'])
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

Comment: Either use `import` at the beginning of the script or inside `choi` function

Comment: Is there any reason to why you are trying to import a module in a function?

Comment: Yes, you *can* import a module in a function, but it won't affect the global namespace, only the local namespace of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the package in a function so it is only imported locally for the scope of the function. So, when the function is exited, the imported package is no longer available.

Generally, the packages are imported at the top of the file:

```
import random

def choi(a):
    choice = random.choice(a) 
    print(choice) # use print to see the output
    return choice # use return to return the output 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    out = choi(['a', 'b'])  # capture the return value in out
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new here.
I knew that, but I'm going to get Student badge. So, I should post question with at least 10 points. Can you please help me by upvoting this question?

Comment: also, make sure to either `print/return` the value else it is not much useful

Comment: Don't worry about upvotes. As far as I know, there is no criteria for asking questions and if you ask good questions, people will upvote it by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think because when you call imp(), you can import random lib, but after close imp() the main funciton can "remember" import this lib, so error.